# Calling readline()'s Tab Completion Directly

Tags: c, readline, libreadline

I know if I want tab completion I can use

```
char *readline (const char *prompt);
```

and I'll get tab completion while it's running, but what if I already have a string that I want to be completed? Is there a specific function in the readline library that I can call directly and send the string as a parameter to have it run tab completion on it?

I've read through a lot of the source code of complete.c to find a main function I could send a string to with no luck.

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html#SEC36) link for information how.

Comment: It looks interesting, I'm not sure if any of the functions let me give them a string to complete though. The biggest one rl_complete() needs an int ignore and an int invoking_key which I think come from a running readline?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly where the C side API lives, but from the BASH side calling of stuff, `compgen` can accept "partial" input.

The main problem is that the "partial" input is typically provided to shell scripts located in /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/"program", so there is a chance that what you seek is not actually "C API" but the output of one or more bash scripts.

Comment: But if I'm building a shell I'm guessing that wouldn't be to much help would it?